# How can I parse this XML with SimpleXML for PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm attempting to parse an XML document, but I am having trouble because I think the XML is not formatted in a way that works easily with SimpleXML. Some elements in the XML can have 0 or more elements and I don't know how to use SimpleXML to pull the data out properly. It appears that SimpleXML "clumps" together elements since the key names in this document are datatypes. I've created a simplified example.

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
  <result kind="Host">
    <headings>
        <heading>Id</heading>
        <heading>Name</heading>
        <heading>IP Addresses</heading>
        <heading>DNS</heading>
        <heading>Timestamp</heading>
        <heading>Type</heading>
    </headings>
    <row>
        <string>38209387</string>
        <string>johnson38</string>
        <string>192.168.1.1</string>
        <string>joe.example.com</string>
        <datetime>Wed Sep  4 22:13:02 2009</datetime>
        <void/>
    </row>
    <row>
        <string>8283324</string>
        <string>smith42</string>
        <list>
            <string>192.168.1.7</string>
            <string>192.168.1.8</string>
        </list>
        <list>
            <string>john.example.com</string>
            <string>nick.example.com</string>
        </list>
        <datetime>Wed Oct  4 12:13:02 2009</datetime>
        <string>Major Server</string>
    </row>
  </result>
</results>
XML;


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($xml->result->row as $row) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";

    //display the 1st IP Address
    echo "IP Address: ".$row->string[2]."<br />";
}
?>
```

Output

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [string] => Array
        (
            [0] => 38209387
            [1] => johnson38
            [2] => 192.168.1.1
            [3] => joe.example.com
        )

    [datetime] => Wed Sep  4 22:13:02 2009
    [void] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [string] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8283324
            [1] => smith42
            [2] => Major Server
        )

    [list] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [string] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 192.168.1.7
                            [1] => 192.168.1.8
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [string] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => john.example.com
                            [1] => nick.example.com
                        )

                )

        )

    [datetime] => Wed Oct  4 12:13:02 2009
)
IP Address: Major Server
```

Comment: It seems perfectly workable to me? What are you trying to do with the data that you can't do?

Comment: I've updated the problem to show the issue I'm facing. Basically one row is not same as the next. For example, the element representing a host may have 0 (shown as </void>) or more IP Addresses.

Comment: Assuming you want `192.168.1.7` as an answer, that would be in `$row->list[0]->string[0];` would it not? A simple `isset` call could help to detect the `<void/>` / absence of `<list/>`.

Comment: Although $row->list[0]->string[0]; will show 192.168.1.7 on this element, it will not work on every element in the XML document. This is a simplified version of an XML document with thousands of entries that I need to pull data from.

Comment: So, by which logic should we find it? Without further info I cannot combine the logic of the scheme and the data you seem to want, so further info might be necessary. If you'd tell it as a story, which node do you want to find, and why that particular node?

Comment: I need to basically extract all the data in each element. The problem is, the key names are the same and it seems as though SimpleXML "clumps" them together making it hard to program a hard rule that $row->list[0]->string[whatever] will always be an IP, name, or whatever. I'm starting to think that SimpleXML may not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now: for instance the IP is always the 3rd element, but may be empty (`<void/>`), contain a single value (`<string/>`), or contain multiple values (a `<list/>` with `<string/>`s). Is that correct? (other 'keys' may be integer/datetime etc.), and you need the order of the direct children of a `<row/>` preserved in order to make out what data they represent?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! Any idea how I'd do that?

Comment: Added an answer, but if order is important, it can indeed get quite tricky with simplexml. As a replacement you can use DOMDocument, which is quite more verbose, but way more powerfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($xml->result->row as $row) {
    //this will still have elements in order, so you'll have to count:
    $count = 1;
    foreach($row->children() as $child){
       //whatever you want.
       $count++
    }
    //if you only want ip (the 3rd node):
    var_dump($row->xpath('*[3]'));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about the $row->children function. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.